Lucas number multiples of Fibonacci pairs
$\newcommand{\GCD}{\operatorname{GCD}}$ For $n=0,1,2,\ldots,$ let $F_n=0,1,1,2,3,5,\ldots$ and $L_n=2,1,3,4,7,11,\ldots$ be the Fibonacci and Lucas sequences. I expect the following is well known, but can someone supply a proof or reference?
Claim: For $n \ge 1$, we have $\GCD(F_{4n+2},F_{4n+3}-1)=L_{2n+1}$ and $(F_{4n+2}/L_{2n+1},(F_{4n+3}-1)/L_{2n+1}) = (F_{2n+1}, F_{2n+2})$.
Examples: For $n=1$, $$\GCD(F_6,F_7-1)=\GCD(8,12)=4=L_3$$ and $(8/4,12/4)=(2,3)=(F_3,F_4)$. For $n=2$, $$\GCD(F_{10},F_{11}-1)=\GCD(55,88)=11=L_5$$ and $(5,8)=(F_5,F_6)$, etc.

The first identity can be derived as the follows. From the identity
$$\displaystyle F_{m+k} + (-1)^k F_{m-k} = L_k F_m,$$
with the choice $m = 2n+2, k = 2n+1$ we have
$$\displaystyle F_{4n+3} - F_1 = L_{2n+1} F_{2n+2}.$$
On the other hand, we have
$$\displaystyle F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\varphi^n - (1 - \varphi)^n \right), L_n = \varphi^n + (1-\varphi)^n$$
where $\varphi = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$. This gives
$$\displaystyle F_{4n+2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\varphi^{2n+1} - (1 - \varphi)^{2n+1} \right) \left(\varphi^{2n+1} + (1 - \varphi)^{2n+1} \right) = F_{2n+1} L_{2n+1}.$$
Clearly, $\gcd(F_{2n+1}, F_{2n+2}) = 1$, and the claim is proved.
The second claim follows from the same argument above.

We can also let $m=2n+1$, $k=0$ to derive $F_{4n+2}=F_{4n+2}-F_0=F_{2n+1}L_{2n+1}$.
